# .replace is not a function - couldn't figure it out

Tags: javascript, replace

This is a new edit to my question, hopefully it will meet the criteria and be considered eligible.

First, I managed to solve the problem. I will now describe the situation and what I think the solution that solve the problem.

My code gets a string (a call number) as an input, re-formats it, parse it to float, and return the call number location within a given set of ranges.

The code is composed of two functions: 1. `formatCallNumber(callNum)` which does the text manipulation to the input. 2. `SortCallNum(callNumInput)` - responsible on the sorting to ranges part.

The problem was in passing values of call number ranges from the sorting function (no.2) to the formatting function (no.1). Although I parsed those values as strings in the sorting function, the `.replace` function produced an error. The solution that I (think) worked, was to parse the values to strings in the formatting function.

The code of the two functions below is updated and seems to be working as expected:

**function 1 - formatting function:**

```
function formatCallNumber(callNum){
  var formatedCallNum = String(callNum);
  formatedCallNum = formatedCallNum.replace(/\D/g,''); // remove all but digits chars from the string (whitespace, dots, etc)
  formatedCallNum = "0." + formatedCallNum; // add "0." to the callNumber string
  formatedCallNum = parseFloat(formatedCallNum); // parse as float - so it could be compared with other decimals
  return (formatedCallNum);
}
```

**Function 2 - the sorting function:**

```
function SortCallNum(callNumInput){
// data [test only]
var shelves = {
    "S1" : {"callStart":"100","callEnd": "223.456", "id": 1},
    "S2" : {"callStart":"223.457","callEnd": "334", "id": 2},
    "S3" : {"callStart":"335","callEnd": "535", "id": 3},
    "S4" : {"callStart":"536","callEnd": "638", "id": 4},
    "S5" : {"callStart":"639","callEnd": "847", "id": 5}
    };
var matchId = "";
document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "you typed the number: " + callNumInput; // output of callNumInput (as inserted by user) 
formatedCallNum = formatCallNumber(callNumInput);

// traverse into shelves object : iteration of objects (key = s1-s5)
for (var key in shelves) {
    if (shelves.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        matchId = shelves[key].id;
        document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "<br>" + (" -- " + "CallEnd is: " + " -- " + shelves[key].callEnd); // display values of object shelves.key.callend
        document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "<br>" + (" -- " + "CallStart is: " + " -- " + shelves[key].callStart); // display values of object shelves.key.callend
        var formatedCallRangeStart =   formatCallNumber(shelves[key].callStart);
        var formatedCallRangeEnd = formatCallNumber(shelves[key].callEnd);
        console.log(formatedCallRangeStart);
        console.log(formatedCallRangeEnd);
        if ((formatedCallNum <= 0) || (formatedCallNum > 1)){alert('call number not in proper range'); break;}      
        if ((formatedCallRangeStart <= formatedCallNum)&&(formatedCallRangeEnd >= formatedCallNum)){break;}
     }
 }
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `callNum = this.callNum;` which `this.callNum` are u referring to? i don't see any callNum other than the parameter!

Comment: True,  will remove that, but still the error remains...

Comment: How are you invoking `SortCallNum`? Provide the code.

Comment: Is `callNum` an object not a string?  You can't do a `.replace()` on an object.  Try `console.log(callNum)` inside your function, what value does it have?

Comment: I am adding the html that invokes SortCallNum.

Comment: @Delosdos true, that's why changed them (callStart and callEnd) to a string in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, everythign should work as expected. It's important to pass a `string` into `SortCallNum`, and not a `number`.

```js
function SortCallNum(callNumInput){
    // data [test only]
    var shelves = {
        "S1" : {"callStart":100,"callEnd": "223", "id": 1},
        "S2" : {"callStart":224,"callEnd": "334", "id": 2},
        "S3" : {"callStart":335,"callEnd": "535", "id": 3},
        "S4" : {"callStart":536,"callEnd": "638", "id": 4},
        "S5" : {"callStart":639,"callEnd": "847", "id": 5}
    };
    var matchId = "";
    document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "you typed the number: " +     callNumInput; // output of callNumInput (as inserted by user) 
    formatedCallNum = formatCallNumber(callNumInput);

    // traverse into shelves object : iteration of objects (key = s1-s5)
    for (var key in shelves) {
        if (shelves.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            matchId = shelves[key].id;
            document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "<br>" + (" -- " + "CallEnd is: " + " -- " + shelves[key].callEnd); // display values of object shelves.key.callend
            document.getElementById("somthing").innerHTML += "<br>" + (" -- " + "CallStart is: " + " -- " + shelves[key].callStart); // display values of object shelves.key.callend
            var formatedCallRangeStart = String(shelves[key].callStart);
            formatedCallRangeStart = formatCallNumber(formatedCallRangeStart);
            var formatedCallRangeEnd = String(shelves[key].callEnd);
            formatedCallRangeEnd = formatCallNumber(formatedCallRangeEnd);
            matchId = shelves[key].id;
            if ((formatedCallRangeStart <= formatedCallNum)&&(formatedCallRangeEnd >= formatedCallNum)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    alert (matchId);
}

function formatCallNumber(callNum){

    // callNum = prompt('enter a call number: ');
    formattedCallNum = callNum.replace(/\D/g,''); // remove all but digits chars    from the string (whitespace, dots, etc)
    formattedCallNum = "0." + formattedCallNum; // add "0." to the callNumber string
    formattedCallNum = parseFloat(formattedCallNum); // parse as float - so it could be compared with other decimals
    return (formattedCallNum);
}

SortCallNum('1337')
```

```html
<div id="somthing"></div>
```

So, this would work `SortCallNum('1337')`, this not `SortCallNum(1337)`...

Another possible cause is that you trust the return-value from `prompt` blindly.

```
<button type="button" onclick="var callNumInput = prompt('enter a call number: '); SortCallNum(callNumInput);"> SortCallNum(test)</button>
```

> When the user clicks the OK button, text entered in the input field is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned. **If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns `null`**.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Example

A bit of sanitization should help:

```
if (callNumInput == null) {
  throw new Error('You have to insert a number between 0 and 999.')
}
```

Comment: @torazaburo I don't see any `this` in the code (anymore) ;)

Comment: it's actually started working!

Comment: @hagaybar Great to hear that. Did you find the problem?

Comment: I think that the solution was to parse the values to strings in the `formatCallNumber(callNum)` function and not the `SortCallNum(callNumInput)` function. I appreciate the help!